# Null values update with Spring Rest Resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

There is a class annotated with RestResource (Spring 3.1, Jackson 2.3). 
When we try save object A like that

```
A: {"prop1":1, "prop2":2}
```

it saved successfully.

We have following code:

```
A.setProp2(null);
EntityService.patch(A);
A: {"prop1":1, "prop2":null}
```

After EntityService.patch(A) execution there is no changes in DB (Oracle 11g), but we want that in DB prop2 will be equals to null too.

Is it a normal behaviour (I think maybe yes, because null-value may understanding like not changed)? 
Is there a simple way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When speaking about the HTTP verbs, the `PATCH` request describes the differences that should be made to the existing object. It is made so that you can easily create partial updates without exposing a particular resource property throught REST.

In Spring framework, in the context of `PATCH` request, the `null` value of a property means no change to the property should be made. I guess that spring data rest transpons this logic to the service layer, so in order to actually update your resource with the `null` value you should issue a call corresponding to the `PUT` semantics

Comment: Exactly what I found, thank you. Some more info - https://spring.io/understanding/REST

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer above is right.

Unfortunately, PUT method update all fields and in some cases it maybe a bad solution. For example if we have many nulls in JSON-object, which wasn't modified.

To make Spring PATCH update null values, only when it's change, the best way that I found is extend DomainObjectMerger class. 
It is a bean of REST MVC config, in which we can override method merge (entity.doWithProperties(new SimplePropertyHandler() {}).
In this method we can add addition condition like

```
sourceValue != targetValue;
```

independent on null value of sourceValue variable.